# Configuration Inspector error...The site's configuration does not match the associated schema

Tags: 8, installation

I have recently started using Drupal 8 and I decided to go with the Varbase distribution. I installed it once and it came up with errors. I figured things were timing out so I increased the execution time in the php.ini (I'm also new to PHP, coming from .NET). So now I have reinstalled the distribution, which takes quite long!!

The issue I am now facing is presented by the Status Report. It is listing 4 errors, one of which I'm not sure what to do about since this is a fresh install: The error is in the CONFIGURATION INSPECTOR:

"The site's configuration does not match the associated schema."

```
bootstrap_barrio.settings: 11 errors
charts.settings: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.node.landing_page.default: 13 errors
core.entity_form_display.node.page.default: 2 errors
core.entity_form_display.node.varbase_heroslider_media.default: 2 errors
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_accordion.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_block.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_carousel.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_columns.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_columns_three_uneven.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_columns_two_uneven.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_image.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_modal.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_simple.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_tabs.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_view.default: 5 errors
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.bp_webform.default: 1 error
core.entity_form_display.paragraph.text_and_image.default: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s01: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s01_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s01_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s01_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s02: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s02_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s02_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s02_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s03: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s03_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s03_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s03_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s04: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s04_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s04_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s04_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s05: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s05_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s05_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s05_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s06: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s06_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s06_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s06_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s07: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s07_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s07_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s07_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s08: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s08_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s08_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s08_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s09: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s09_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s09_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s09_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s10: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s10_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s10_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s10_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s11: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s11_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s11_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s11_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s12: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s12_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s12_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.s12_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.se2e: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.se2e_4_1: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.se2e_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.se2e_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.se2e_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.image.token: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s01: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s01_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s01_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s01_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s02: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s02_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s02_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s02_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s03: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s03_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s03_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s03_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s04: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s04_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s04_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s04_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s05: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s05_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s05_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s05_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s06: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s06_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s06_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s06_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s07: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s07_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s07_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s07_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s08: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s08_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s08_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s08_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s09: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s09_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s09_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s09_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s10: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s10_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s10_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s10_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s11: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s11_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s11_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s11_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s12: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s12_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s12_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.s12_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.se2e: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.se2e_4_1: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.se2e_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.se2e_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.remote_video.se2e_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s01: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s01_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s01_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s01_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s02: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s02_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s02_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s02_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s03: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s03_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s03_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s03_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s04: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s04_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s04_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s04_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s05: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s05_square: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s05_standard: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s05_traditional: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s06: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s06_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s06_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s06_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s07: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s07_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s07_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s07_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s08: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s08_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s08_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s08_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s09: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s09_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s09_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s09_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s10: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s10_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s10_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s10_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s11: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s11_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s11_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s11_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s12: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s12_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s12_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.s12_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.se2e: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.media.video.se2e_4_1: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.se2e_square: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.se2e_standard: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.media.video.se2e_traditional: 1 error
core.entity_view_display.node.page.default: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.node.page.full: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser: 2 errors
core.entity_view_display.paragraph.bp_view.default: 1 error
editor.editor.basic_html: 1 error
editor.editor.code_html: 1 error
editor.editor.full_html: 2 errors
embed.button.gallery: 1 error
embed.button.media: 1 error
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.editor_media_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.editor_multiple_image_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.editor_multiple_media_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.image_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.media_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.multiple_image_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.multiple_media_browser: 2 errors
entity_browser_enhanced.widgets.video_browser: 2 errors
field.field.paragraph.bp_accordion.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_block.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_carousel.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_columns.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_columns_three_uneven.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_columns_two_uneven.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_image.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_modal.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_simple.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_tabs.bp_width: 1 error
field.field.paragraph.bp_view.bp_view: 5 errors
field.field.paragraph.bp_view.bp_width: 1 error
field.storage.paragraph.bp_view: 1 error
filter.format.basic_html: 1 error
filter.format.code_html: 1 error
filter.format.full_html: 1 error
media.type.image: 1 error
page_manager.page_variant.total_control_dashboard-http_status_code-0: 7 errors
page_manager.page_variant.total_control_dashboard-panels_variant-0: 4 errors
page_manager.page_variant.total_control_dashboard-panels_variant-1: 6 errors
redirect.settings: 7 errors
seckit.settings: 1 error
simple_sitemap.settings: 1 error
syslog.settings: 1 error
tour.tour.media-hero-slider-creation: 1 error
tour.tour.varbase-dashboard-tour: 1 error
tour.tour.welcome-to-varbase: 1 error
vartheme_bs4.settings: 61 errors
views.view.content: 22 errors
views.view.control_terms: 1 error
views.view.media: 8 errors
views.view.media_browsers: 6 errors
views.view.media_library: 7 errors
views.view.redirect_404: 1 error
views.view.user_admin_people: 7 errors
```

What do I do? Is there a way to fix this? When I open any of these errors for more detail I see a list of configuration data for those particular settings. Most but not all of the errors have label and type 'Undefined'/ 'undefined' and the error message 'missing schema'.

Comment: How exactly did you go about installing it?

Comment: For the first part of the installation I got the distribution using composer running the command composer create-project Vardot/varbase-project YOUR_PROJECT --no-dev --no-interaction. Next I ran the install script at http://<my-site-name>/core/install.php

Comment: Try `composer create-project vardot/varbase-project:^8.7.5 PROJECT_DIR_NAME --no-dev --no-interaction` if still the same result, then [maybe its bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/varbase/issues/3116908)?

Comment: I can try that but before I do, is there a reason for that particular version? I was trying to verify which version I did actually install, the only info I could find was on the Admin > Reports > Updates page. varbase 8.x-8.3 and varbase_core 8.x-8.4.

Comment: `is there a reason for that particular version?` just following the [README.md](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/varbase/-/blob/8.x-7.x/README.md) file, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, re-installed and the issue is no longer there.